# Start another background process after the completion of first automatically

Tags: swift, background-process

I have this method

```
func reminderInitialSetup() {
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() 

        for i in (0..<self.arrayMyGoals.count) {

            let tempDict1 = self.arrayMyGoals[i] as! NSMutableDictionary;

            var goal_days : String!

            guard let days = tempDict1.value(forKey: "goal_dates") as? String else{
                return
            }
            goal_days = days

            let goal_time = tempDict1.value(forKey: "goal_time") as! String;

            let goal_name = tempDict1.value(forKey: "goal_name") as! String;

            let goalId : Int!

            goalId = tempDict1.object(forKey: "goal_id") as? Int                
            if goal_days.count > 0 {

                var datesArray = [Any]()

                datesArray = goal_days.components(separatedBy: ",")

                for  j in (0..<datesArray.count){

                    self.setReminder(date: datesArray[j] as! String, time: goal_time, title: goal_name, goalId: String(goalId))

                }
            }


        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        }
    }

}
```

This method is called when I get response from webservice on button click in background. When I press the button again it happens that method is getting executed in background and number of object in arrayMyGoals changes which gives crash. 
I want to start the another background process automatically after the completion of previous

How can I achieve this

Comment: You should take a look at [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue).

Answer (score 1):

You can use operation queues for this. Example:

```
let operationQueue: OperationQueue = {
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    operationQueue.qualityOfService = .background
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    return operationQueue
}()

func runTask(id: String) {
    // optional: cancel all previous operations if about to start a new one
    // operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
    operationQueue.addOperation {
        var wait = 0
        for _ in 0 ..< 10000 {
            wait += 1
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("task \(id) finished")
        }
    }
}

runTask(id: "t1")
runTask(id: "t2")
runTask(id: "t3")
```

Output:

```
task t1 finished
task t2 finished
task t3 finished
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new queue for every task though? Don't you want all tasks added to the same queue? (Genuine questions, never used operation queues myself)

Comment: The `operationQueue` variable is instantiated only once. This is just a playground example, in a real world this would probably be a lazy instance property.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a serial queue, and on each button press I would increment a counter in a process (eg func incrementRequestCount()) on this serial queue to indicate how many requests need to be made.

I would then start a process (eg func invokeWebRequestIfNeeded()) on this serial queue that checks the value of the counter, and if it is greater than 0, decrements it and calls your method to make the web request.

When I got the response from the web I would do any required processing (on the serial queue) and then call invokeWebRequestIfNeeded() again.

If the user has pressed the button while this has been happening, then the counter will be one or more, so invokeWebRequestIfNeeded() will call your method again.

Eventully the count of required requests will drop to zero and invokeWebRequestIfNeeded() will exit without action.

There may be more swiftian ways to do this.... but when rushed I like things simple and obvious.

Comment: I don't want the user to wait when reminderInitialSetup() is called. Coz if it will be a longer wait time everytime user clicks on button

Comment: So you want your requests to be made in parallel, but your responses serialised?  I think you need to isolate the contended resource (arrayMyGoals) behind a serial queue so that all access (or at least writes) are serialised.  This is a slightly more difficult task, but a common one.  If all access to the contended resource are quick then there should not be too much of a performance hit.  You will need to ensure that you iterate over a *copy* of the array, too.